# Moving the db folder created by bundle exec rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, rake

What my file structure usually looks like is this:

```
├── mainAppFolder
│   ├── app.rb
│   ├── rakefile
│   └── db
│       ├── schema.rb
|       └── migrations
```

I would like to change it to:

```
├── mainAppFolder
│   ├── app.rb
│   ├── rakefile
|   └── database
│       └── db
│           ├── schema.rb
|           └── migrations
```

I think that this might involve editing a rake task and using `Dir.chdir("./database")` but I can't figure out how to do it. Googling only got my a question using `config.path` which is only relevant to rails and I am using sinatra. How can I make this work?

Comment: Why do you want to fight `ActiveRecord` conventions? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: A neat looking project folder

Comment: putting `db` folder (which stands for database) into `database` folder is by no means neat. By this same logic you should be willing to put `app` into `application` folder, `config` into `configuration` and so on - IMO senseless

Comment: db is not the only thing in there. I have a buncha other files in there for database related tasks.

Comment: (Sorry about the offtopic answer.) Came to think of another thing - I moved the schema file to a rails engine and used the env variable `SCHEMA` to point to the new place of the schema file. I would suspect that it is something that active record uses.

Answer (score -1):

while i strongly advise against changing the default paths, i think that you can do it like it's advertised in the [rails docs](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb#L31-L34):

```
include ActiveRecord::Tasks
DatabaseTasks.database_configuration = YAML.load_file('my_database_config.yml')
DatabaseTasks.db_dir = 'db'
```

since you have not actually posted how exactly you are using active-record in your sinatra application, this is just a guess.